# How can I pass object[] or several objects to enqueueworkitem method?

Tags: c#

The parameterizedthreadstart object has an enqueueworkitem. This (if I can remember my methods and their parameters correctly) takes an object parameter as "state".

However, when I have a method which has several object parameters (e.g. string, int which are children of object) what can I do to pass all of these parameters into the enqueueworkitem method? Also, what if I have an object[] and not object parameter?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly legal to pass an object[] to a function that takes object.  Any type is convertible to object.

In the called function simply cast the state parameter back to object[] and you're good to go.

```
public void CallThreadPool(object[] arguments) {
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallBack(MyThreadProc), arguments);
}

public void MyThreadProc(object state) {
  object[] data = (object[])state;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always wrap any number of arguments you need in a type and pass an instance of that.

Comment: Thanks. I actually just saw that approac on a similar thread on here :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd avoid the "state" param - it loses type safety (the cast isn't checked by the compiler). Anonymous methods are cleaner:

```
int foo =...;
string bar =...;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
    YourMethod(foo,bar);
});
```